# How to sum columns from two MySQL tables with many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I need to retrieve the values for each student like the following

```
student full name | costs | discounts | net Value | payments | remaining
```

when I try

```
SELECT 
    concat_ws(' ',students.firstname,students.secondname,students.thirdname,students.forthname,students.lastname),
        students.birthdate,
        sum(costs.value),
        sum(discounts.value),
        sum(costs.value)-sum(discounts.value),
        sum(payments.amount),
        sum(costs.value)-sum(discounts.value)-sum(payments.amount)     

FROM students
JOIN coststudents 
       ON  coststudents.student_id = students.student_id 
 JOIN costs  
    ON  costs.cost_id = coststudents.cost_id
JOIN discountstudent 
       ON  discountstudent.student_id = students.student_id 
JOIN discounts  
    ON  discounts.id = discountstudent.id
JOIN payments 
       ON  payments.student_id = students.student_id
```

it only gives me the one row out and does not correspond to the query.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Put GROUP BY students.student_id at the end of the code.

Edit: Instead JOIN use LEFT JOIN.

Comment: no it get data that not responding with what I want to get and the calculation is all wrong !